# Calculate new values in R time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset of the type

```
ID      variable       value
200         B/L         81.3    
200         Wk2         6.1
200         Wk4         2.0
200         Wk8         2.2
201         B/L         123.3
201         Wk2         89.3
201         Wk4         72.4    
201         Wk8         55.8
```

I'd like to add rows with the change in the variable between timepoints eg

```
ID      variable       value
200         B/L         81.3    
200         deltaB/L    NA
200         Wk2         6.1
200         deltaWk2    -75.2
200         Wk4         2.0
200         deltaWk4    -4.1
200         Wk8         2.2
200         deltaWk8    0.2
201         B/L         123.3
201         deltaB/L    NA
201         Wk2         89.3
201         deltaWk2    -34
201         Wk4         72.4    
201         deltaWk4    -16.9
201         Wk8         55.8
201         deltaWk8    -16.6
```

Any idea on how to do this efficiently?

Comment: I would recommend adding new column `data$delta <- c(NA, diff(data$value))`

Answer (score 0):

The `variable` column seems like it could be an ordered factor, but fortunately the order coincides with alphabetical order. Creating a new column for delta seems like a good idea, but that's not what you've asked for. The code below produces the output you describe.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(200,200,200,200,201,201,201,201),
  variable = c('B/L', 'Wk2', 'Wk4', 'Wk8', 'B/L', 'Wk2', 'Wk4', 'Wk8'),
  value = c(81.3, 6.1, 2.0, 2.2, 123.3, 89.3, 72.4, 55.8))

group_by(df, ID) %>%
  do({mutate(., value = c(NA, diff(value)),
             variable = paste0(unique(variable), 'delta'))}) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(ID, variable)
```